# How to sort my list? Help

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a `list={1,2,3,4,5,-6,9,3,12,0,-3}`. I want to sort its, as way {even,odd,even,odd,....}. Moreover in crescent way for even and odd numbers. So  the result must be `{-6,-3,0,1,2,3,4,3,12,5,9}`.

Comment: Are there always equal ($\pm1$) numbers of evens and odds? If so, `Riffle @@ Sort /@ GatherBy[%, EvenQ]` or `Riffle @@ Sort /@ Reverse @ GatherBy[%, EvenQ]`.

Comment: What should the list `{6, 4, 2, 1}` return? What should the list `{5, 3, 1, 0}` return? Should even numbers always come first, or odd? -- or is the smallest value always first? In other words, please specify your exact problem more carefully. (By the way, `%` in my last comment should be `list`.)

Comment: Ok. I have a list={1,2,3,4,5,-6,9,3,12,0,-3}. I want to sort its, as way {even,odd,even,odd,....}. Moreover in crescent way for even and odd numbers.So  the result must be list2={-6,-3,0,1,2,3,4,3,12,5,9}

Comment: That's a repeat of what you posted in the question. I'm asking what the result should be for more general lists. What if there are many more even numbers than odd numbers? Do the extra evens get appended to the end of the list? Should the first even number *always* come first? Etc. Please edit your question (by pressing the grey edit button below your post) with these specifics.

Comment: Question is both ill-defined and too localized, and OP does not respond sensibly to requests for clarification.

Answer (score 4):

Building on march's proposal this may be a bit more robust, though it is still based on guesswork:

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -6, 9, 3, 12, 0, -3}

Flatten[{False, True} /. GroupBy[Sort @ list, OddQ], {2, 1}]
```

> ```
> {-6, -3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 12, 5, 9}
> ```

That assumes you always want to start with an even number.  If not this is shorter:

```
Sort[list] ~GatherBy~ OddQ ~Flatten~ {2, 1}
```

> ```
> {-6, -3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 12, 5, 9}
> ```